# Partition `[String]` by the first `Char` of each `String`

Tags: string, haskell, partitioning

I am attempting to write a function with the following type:

```
partitionByFirstChar :: [String] -> Map.Map Char [String]
```

`partitionByFirstChar xs` will return a `Map` whose keys are the first character of each string in the list `xs` and whose values are a list of the suffixes (i.e. all but the first character) of those strings.

My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
partitionByFirstChar [] = Map.empty
partitionByFirstChar ((x:xs):xss)
  = ???
    where partitioned = partitionByFirstChar xss
          suffixes = partitioned !? x
```

Now `suffixes` can be either `Nothing` or `Just s`. If it is `Nothing`, I want to `insert x [xs] partitioned`. If it is `Just s`, then I want to `insert x (xs:s) partitioned`.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to check what `suffixes` is. I think I need some kind of pattern matching for the `???` but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: I think this does the trick too... `partitionByFirstChar ss = fromListWith (++) [ (c,[s]) | (c:s) <- ss ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use the [`multimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multimap) package, it solves this problem quite readily.

```
λ> import qualified Data.MultiMap as MM

λ> MM.toMap . MM.fromList . fmap (\(x:xs) -> (x, xs)) $ ["apple", "avocado", "bagel"]
fromList [('a',["pple","vocado"]),('b',["agel"])]
```

`fromListWith`, as @Alec's comment points out, is probably a better choice if you don't need to use the `MultiMap` type. Although the performance might not be great, due to the list concatenation.

```
λ> import qualified Data.Map as M

λ> M.fromListWith (<>) . fmap (\(x:xs) -> (x, [xs])) $ ["apple", "avocado", "bagel"]
fromList [('a',["vocado","pple"]),('b',["agel"])]
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this tomorrow. What I am doing definitely lends itself to a multimap. I will probably change the type of the function at return a MultiMap.

Comment: Actually, I reckon performance of the `fromListWith` variant can be fine with either `(<>)` or `(flip (<>))`.

Comment: I decided to go with `MultiMap` as the return value of my function.

Answer (score 0):

> Now `suffixes` can be either `Nothing` or `Just s`. If it is `Nothing`, I want to `insert x [xs] partitioned`. If it is `Just s`, then I want to `insert x (xs:s) partitioned`.

A basic approach here is to use `case of`:

```
partitionByFirstChar [] = Map.empty
partitionByFirstChar ((x:xs):xss) = let
   partitioned = partitionByFirstChar xss
   suffixes = partitioned !? x
   in case suffixes of
      Nothing -> insert x [xs] partitioned
      Just s -> insert x (xs:s) partitioned
```

The code above still lacks a branch for the empty string, e.g.:

```
partitionByFirstChar ("":xss) = partitionByFirstChar xss
```